# What is the best approach to perform updations on Hadoop File System?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, avro

What is the best approach to perform updations on Hadoop File System ? For Instance I have one avro file which contains data, for the next run I need to update the data in the avro file itself.How can we approach this problem ?

Ex : I have the below data on HDFS, need to update the "subDistricts" array for the next time

> {   "name": "DistrictName",   "_class":
>   "org.bitbucket.codezarvis.api.dto.DistrictDocument",   "type":
>   "district",   "subDistricts": [
>       256,
>       257
>          ]  }

Answer (score 0):

HDFS is designed as a write-once, append-only file system.  That said you have a couple of options for performing update-ish operations:

- Use HBase, which provides a no-sql system on top of the underlying HDFS files.  Bear in mind it hides the magic from you, but it still has to perform the operations that you would have had to do - make a copy of a file, replacing just the portion(s) necessary, swapping out the file, etc.  Its performance will not be stellar, but it will get the job done.
- Hive INSERT OVERWRITE will allow you to run a query which performs the updates/calculations, and then overwrites the table with the updated data.  Or you could limit your overwrite to a single partition, and then get thoughtful about how you manage your partitions.
- Don't update, always write new rows/files.  When you have new data write it into a new partition, even if its replacing other data.  When you select data from the table always select only the latest partition.  Your history of data will continue to grow and you can drop those older partitions at another time.

Words of advice - if you find yourself in this situation a lot in hadoop, reconsider whether hadoop is the best choice.  ACID is best done by SQL solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Richard Kemp

Answer (score 0):

Schema evolution is a generic concept for modifying the schema without rewriting the existing data.
If the data is stored in Hive table as AVRO ( underlying data is stored in HDFS ), then the schema can be changed.
(Though there are some limitations to that also).

Comment: Thanks Deepan Ram for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

Also I came up with an approch and design of the Document

```
{
    "diffs": [{
        "before": null,
        "after": {
            "org.bitbucket.codezarvis.api.dto.DistrictDocument": {
                "districtId": {
                    "mostSigBits": -917,
                    "leastSigBits": -562
                },
                "state": null,
                "subDistricts": {
                    "array": [{
                        "subDistrictId":111,
                        "longitudeOfPoi": {
                            "string": "1.52256"
                        },                      
                        "latitudeOfPoi": {
                            "string": "42.543528"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
```

The AVRO file with Diff entries that contains the deltas that have to be applied to the next run.

A Diff contains one or more Diff entries that have a relation to each other.

The Diff contains for each modified, deleted or added Sub district entry with the 'before' and 'after' information.

If a subDistrict is added compared to the previous run, the 'before' will be null.
If a subDistrict is deleted compared to the previous run the 'after' will be null.

If a subDistrict is modified compared to the previous run, both the 'before' and 'after' will exists.

The existance of a delta record in the output can have these reasons:
The District was changed, added or deleted compared to the previous output that was there on HDFS.